# How can I test whether a node is connected (with edges) in a graph?

Tags: java, graph, linked-list, nodes, adjacency-list

Trying to be simple: 
If I have a Graph of cities like:

Berlin(edges: London, Berlin) --next--> London(edges: Paris) --next--> Paris.

And I have a method to disconnect Nodes e.g.

disconnect(London, Paris);

I want to test (JUnit) if the disconnect was successful. My idea: write a method isStillConnected(London) which returns false, if London has no edge-list/ if edge-list is null, else true. Code idea:

```
public boolean isStillConnected(ListItem<Node<City, Road>> berlin) {
    boolean edgeExists = false;
    if(berlin.key.edgesGoingToHere.key.whereEdgeGoesTo != null) {
        edgeExists = true;
    }
    return edgeExists;      
}
```

PROBLEM: If the edge hasn't got an edge (which I am requesting), there is a NULLPOINTER because I want to access "whereEdgeGoesTo" which is null.

edgesGoingToHere is the head of the Edge-list.
whereEdgeGoesTo is the Node, where the Edge is pointing at.

Thanks for any answer!

Comment: You used `disconnect(London,Paris)` as an example. Is your goal to disconnect London from all other nodes or only to disconnect London from Paris? Or is your goal to disconnect London from all other nodes as well as Paris?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your objects structure just by looking at that small portion of code, but assuming that the if statement is checking the right values, to avoid a `nullPointerException`, instead of reading the values in the list and comparing them to null check the size of the list using `.size()`  and return true if that value is higher than 0.